# How do I make my app work for any screen size in both landscape and portrait mode?

Tags: android

my app currently works perfectly in landscape and portrait mode for large screen. In smaller screens it only works in portrait mode. I've tried making it scrollable but I don't seem to get it right any suggestions?

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SpeedActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroller1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleX="1.0"
                    android:scaleY="1.0"
                    android:src="@drawable/uzcrest" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Department of Computer Science"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SmartDrive Demo"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Current Speed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCurrentSpeed"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:editable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="0.0 km/h"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>



</TableLayout>
```

I also included the following in my android manifest file:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a `layout-land` directory and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept the answer to let anyone having similar problem know.

Answer (score 1):

First create **layout-land** folder in **res** folder in your apps. and create xml file for landscape.
other technique is use this code in your activity class

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create layout-land folder inside your res folder and copy your landscape layout XML into layout-land. After copying the layout XML give  as parent. And Remember one thing if you are using "android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest, than you have to remove this tag or you have to override OnConfigChange() method in your activity and you have to call setContentView again.